# Flexslider in modal window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, flexslider

I am using flexslider in a modal window. When I open the modal window, the flexslider appears as well as the next/prev navigation.  However, the navigation does not work at first.  If I wait a few minutes and go back to the page, the navigation works properly.

I have checked firebug and I don't see anything that would be hindering the script.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this here https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

To be more cocrete.

You should execute `$(window).trigger('resize');` on the open event of your modal.